# Identify troubling spec with rspec in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec

I've got this monstrous error message while running `rspec spec/vector_spec.rb` and I couldn't identify what spec is causing an error.

Here's some part of the error message:

```
..................F...........******************************...........F...***********************....*.....*....................................../home/ubuntu/workspace/daru/lib/daru/index.rb:102: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x007fe1e31ce030
ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0048 p:0021 s:0197 e:000196 METHOD /home/ubuntu/workspace/daru/lib/daru/index.rb:102
c:0047 p:0015 s:0193 e:000192 METHOD /home/ubuntu/workspace/daru/lib/daru/vector.rb:207
...
```

Here's the full error message: https://gist.github.com/lokeshh/83369d71ca94b07cf89b23e215214666

I want to know which spec is causing an error so I can look into it but I couldn't find a way to identify the spec that is causing the error.

Is there way?

Answer (score 0):

You can append a colon and then the line number of the specific test to the RSpec file, e.g.:

```
rspec spec/vector_spec.rb:83
```

You could also disable large parts of your code with `=begin` and `=end` to narrow down the section.

***I just ran `rspec -h` and got some very helpful information.  Check out the `--only-failures` and `next-failure` options!  Also, looks like you could also use `-fd` to get the groups and example names printed out!***

Comment: Did this help at all?